# Differentiate case sensitive in query result with eloquent+mysql

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to have a request with a case sensitive result with eloquent.

For example in my database I have

```
 1ABC
 2Abc
 3abc
```

```
 User::where('code', 'LIKE', "%$code%")->get() or User::where('code', '=', $code)->get()
```

but I have my 3 rows as result and I just want 2Abc

Comment: You have `ci` collation set on the table/column. That's not laravel. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: Thanks! +1 for your answer

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: there you go mates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's feature of the database not Laravel itself. In MySql you can define `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` on different levels (DB, connection, table, column - see the docs).

In your case you must be using `ci` - case insensitive collaction, so you need to change that in your db.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-mysql.html